# How can we avoid having to manually refresh the Sheet after our Add-on is installed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a few Google Sheets Add-ons and all of them require a reload of the Sheet in order for the Add-on to be used. The user installs it fine and it shows up in the Add-on menu but they are unable to actually use the Add-on until they reload the sheet. This happens for all of our users and in our own tests. We have:

```
function onInstall() {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem("Do something", "showSidebar")
  .addItem("Do something else", "showSidebar")
  .addToUi(); 
}

function showSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("myhtml");
  html = html.evaluate().setTitle("Our so great of a title");  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Are we missing anything obvious that will load the menu automatically when the Add-on is installed. This is our general template and it happens with all of our Add-ons.

Comment: Doesn't the add-on appear when the Spreadsheet is opened? or you mean for only the first time when the add-on is recently installed?

Comment: Only happens when the add-on is recently installed. It appears fine if you refresh the sheet or close then reopen it.

Comment: Are you installing a published Add-on from G Suite Marketplace or an [unpublished add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on)?

Comment: It's published in the marketplace

Comment: Your code should be working fine, I suggest you open a case with [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213)

Comment: There is an open issue. Please star it if it affects you: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147016387